# Check that Files Execute Concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to perform 2 tasks independently.

**First Task**

Once per minute it should check whether there is any file in a specific folder. If there is, it should add the names of the files to a queue.

This can be done as follows:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class schedulerExample extends Thread{

    public void checkFile()
    {
        System.out.println("checking whether file exist in folder");

    }

    public void getFiles()
    {
        System.out.println("getting the file names");
    }

    public void enqueueFiles()
    {
        System.out.println("add files to queue");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    final schedulerExample obj = new schedulerExample();
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            obj.checkFile();
            obj.getFiles();
            obj.enqueueFiles();

        }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);


    }

}
```

**Second Task**

If the queue is empty , sleep for one minute or else process the file from the queue one-by-one.

```
public class processModel extends Thread{

    public static void getQueueSize(int size)
    {
        System.out.println("getting queue size");

    }
    public void dequeue()
    {

        // dequeue the queue
        System.out.println("dequeue");

    }

    public void processFile()
    {
        // process the file
        System.out.println("process file");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final boolean flag = true;
        final int size = 9;
        final processModel obj = new processModel();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(){
            public void run()
            {
                while(flag)
                {
                obj.dequeue();
                obj.processFile();
                getQueueSize(size);
                    if(size == 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                        Thread.sleep(60000);
                        }
                        catch(InterruptedException e)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        };

        t1.start();

    }

}
```

Now I need to do both in a single class concurrently. Is that possible?

One thread should be fetching the files once per minute. Another thread should execute files one-by-one.. if no files are there it waits for a minute and checks again. In the second method I have used an infinite loop -- instead of that, is there a way that I can perform things one-by-one?

Comment: What if the first file is still being processed?

Comment: Class names should start with an upper-case letter; fields, method parameters and variables should start with lower-case letters. This is the style convention for Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronize on the queue object when you get file from it and when you add file to it.

In the thread that reads, call `wait()` if the queue is empty.
In the thread that checks for new files, call `notify()` after you added the new file to the queue.

This is how it's usually done.

---

You should also prevent adding file that is being processed to the queue.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider using [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)s with the java [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).  This can be used to easily break up tasks and allow them to run concurrently.  Beyond that, you can get a Future which will allow you to check the results at any time (or postpone if it's not done).

There is a great book about java and concurrency called "Concurrency in Practice."

Beyond that, Java 7 has new functionality to allow file listeners on directories. That might allow you to abstract this "check and loop" functionality.